# split csv file in python by top 30 column values

Tags: python, csv, file, split

suppose i have huge data file contain type column

```
Date            Day Of Week Type
4/9/2015 0:00   Thursday    BATTERY
3/9/2015 0:00   Monday      THEFT
4/3/2015 0:00   Friday      DECEPTIVE PRACTICE
1/1/2015 0:01   Thursday    DECEPTIVE PRACTICE
4/10/2015 0:01  Friday      OTHER OFFENSE
3/27/2015 0:01  Friday      DECEPTIVE PRACTICE
4/10/2015 0:35  Friday      BATTERY
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93d3i.png)

can i generate csv file with top 30 types in this file?

Comment: What do you mean by "TOP"?

Comment: How do you define `top 30 values`? Is it by frequency of occurrence?

Comment: Also, please post the expected output based on this sample input.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the command **.groupby()** together with the **.count()** and the **.sort_values()** command on the newly-created *count* column:

```
df_grouped = df[['Type','Date']].groupby(['Type'])['Date'] \
                                .count() \
                                .reset_index(name='count') \
                                .sort_values(['count'], ascending=False)

df_top_types = df_grouped.iloc[0:2][:]
```

For the sake of this example, I only retrieve the first two rows of the new DataFrame, in your case, select the first 30 rows.

You can then save the new DataFrame as a *.csv* using the following command:

```
df_top_types.to_csv('CSV_Top_Type.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

The csv file will be saved in your current working environment under the name 'CSV_Top_Type.csv'.

Alternatively, depending on the format you want your data stored, you could use the following code:

```
df = df[['Type','Date']].groupby(['Type'])['Date'].count().nlargest(2)
df.to_csv('CSV_Top_Type.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Select 30 as the parameter given to the command **.nlargest()**.